# Resize the UV Grid texture tiles

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a rather silly question that, i'm 90% sure, has already been answered here but i cannot find a way to word a search to get the right result. So sorry for that.

I like the default UV Grid texture that blender generates but in some cases,(like with low resolution images) the grid's tiles are way bigger than most of the poly i have on my model so it's not really useful to spot the stretching.

So i was wondering if there is a way to make the tiles smaller without having to manually import my own UV grid? (it's easy to work around but i'd like using the shortcut rapidly from blender's UI)
Thanks

[image: The UV grid in question]

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but you mention about spotting the stretching. Do you know that in the UV Editor there is an option you can check in the Viewport Overlays to Display Stretch? Maybe that will help you see what you need to.

Comment: Yes i knew about this function but it doesnt make the stretching obvious like the good old black and white (actually grey lol) tiles. it also doesnt help with the texture rotation

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution, you just need to ignore the limit of the visible grid entirely and scale your UVs, even outside of the grid.